# RubyKoans 113/282 - type mismatch:string given / how could i have solved myself with irb?

Tags: ruby

When attempting to finish up the about_method koans, I keep running into a "type mismatch:String given" error on lines 39 & 42. My first question is why the error? My second question is how could I have solved this myself with irb?

## Koan

```
 require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/neo')

 def my_global_method(a,b)
   a + b
 end

    class AboutMethods < Neo::Koan

    def test_calling_global_methods_with_wrong_number_of_arguments
        exception = assert_raise(ArgumentError) do
          my_global_method
        end

        assert_match(/__/, exception.message)

        exception = assert_raise(ArgumentError) do
          my_global_method(1,2,3)
        end
        assert_match(/__/, exception.message)
      end
    #...
    end
```

## Error & My Work

A. If I change the assert to

> assert_match(/"wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)"/, exception.message)

it results in:

> Expected "wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)" to match / "wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)" /

B. If I change it to

> assert_match("wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)", exception.message)

it results in:

> type mismatch: String given

I get the same results for both assert_match lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first failure is because parentheses are special characters in regex's, so you need to escape them with a backslash. You also have quotes in the regex, which don't exist in the string.  The second failure is presumably because `assert_match` expects a regex as the first argument.

As for using irb to debug these problems, you could have used irb to see if the actual string matched the regex you provided as in the following:

```
2.0.0p247 :001 >  /"wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)"/ =~ "wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)"
 => nil
```

You could then whittle down the left and right hand side until they match and then add back characters until you figured out the problem characters.

I'm not sure how irb could have helped with the second problem.

Comment: Thanks @Peter I didn't realize that anything in /../ would be a regex, I assumed they were placeholders like the __

Answer (score 6):

```
assert_match(/wrong number of arguments \(0 for 2\)/, exception.message)
```

Without double quotes and escape brackets.

Comment: I know I shouldn't ask a question in my answer. I just not sure should I wirite the answer straight..

Answer (score 2):

```
/["wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)"]/
```

worked for me